# File does not have a main method class error in netbeans (java swing)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

I am trying to implement a database management system in netBeans using Java swing,However,when I tried to include a functionality that returns the query result in a jTable by clicking a button and based on input values entered I encounter an error.It says the file does not have a main method class. How am I suppose to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

> It says the file does not have a main method class.

So you add a `main(...)` method.

Maybe start with an example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Download the examples to see how to structure your code so that a main() method exists and the main() method creates your GUI on the `Event Dispatch Thread`.

Comment: The primary class has three argument. Should I pass all three in the main?